# Let $p\in (1,a)$ and $y''+py=0$ with $y(0)=2$ and $y(\pi)$=3 then what is the max value of $a$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $p\in (1,a)$ and $y''+py=0$ with $y(0)=2$ and $y(\pi)=3$ then what is the max value of $a$?

What I tried:

I used the characteristic equation $r^2+p=0$ then $r=±i\sqrt p$

general solution $y(x)=c_1cos(\sqrt px)+c_2sin(\sqrt px)$

with $y(0)=2, c_1=2 $

then with $y(\pi)=3$,

$2cos(\sqrt p\pi)+c_2sin(\sqrt p\pi)=3$

but then I am stuck, how can I find max value of $a$? Anyone can help me please? I would be very glad if you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if $\sin(\sqrt p \pi) = 0$ then this equation cannot be satisfied. This occurs when $\sqrt p \pi = n \pi$ or when $p = n^2$. Hence the open interval $(1,a)$ will have solutions provided that $a = 4$.